# DNN 7.4.2 Custom Registration / Login Module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have DNN 7.4.2 installed. Besides standard registration/login I would also like to utilize Facebook,Twiiter,Windows Live, and Google authentication.  However, I don't like the current workflow. I am now familiar using the Christoc templates to build custom modules, but is this what I want to do, or do I need to build a custom authentication provider.  A lot of the examples out there reference old versions of DNN.

Here's the flow I want:

1) If User is not logged into site, check to see if they are logged into one of the social sites, and if so check their id to see if it is associated with a User on my site.  If so, log them in automatically to my site.

2) If User is not logged in yet, display "Register" and "Login" Links on my menu.

3) If they click the "Register" link, a jquery popup should appear. Buttons for normal registration, and a button each for registering with one of the social sites should appear.

4) If they click on the regular registration, they should go directly to un-pre-populated registration form.

5) If they click on one of the social buttons, it should retrieve whatever info it can from the particular social site, and then go to the same registration form, but pre-populate the controls with the info it retrieved.

6) The registration form should have all the standard fields, plus a place for the avatar (which can be prepopulated from the pic retrieved from social site). In addition, I am using DISQUS comments, and so I want them to be able to enter their DISQUS login info and/or create a DISQUS account.

7) Once the user hits submit, only then is the User actually created. User should be returned to whatever page they were on when they started the registration process.

8) If User is not logged in, and they click "Login" link, a jquery popup will give them Username/Password controls if they want to login in standardly, and also have buttons for logging in with each of the social sites.

9) Id login is unsuccessful, jquery popup content would be replaced with "Unsuccessful" content, and content for retrieving lost usernames / passwords.

10) If login is successful, then they should also be logged into DISQUS.

If there is already a good module that will do all this, then I would prefer just to spend $100-$200 to get it.  However, if there isn't, I would just like a push in the right direction on how to program all of this.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) If User is not logged into site, check to see if they are logged
>   into one of the social sites, and if so check their id to see if it is
>   associated with a User on my site. If so, log them in automatically to
>   my site.

This point is unpossible. Every web page is isolated from each other. You can't determine that user is logged in or not in another webpage. Also you can't identify not logged user (in your website) to check if he is logged in with API (by userId).

I thnik all other points can be reached by this module: http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/social-login-and-social-sharing.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at this, but it's paid subscription that costs almost $400/month for their basic silver plan.  I wouldn't mind paying some one-time money to purchase a good module, but this service is way out of my league.

Answer (score 0):

While I thank Aram for his suggestion, I believe I am going to have to write my own custom authentication providers from scratch.  I hate the fact that I could get no other responses.  I also hate the fact that there is seemingly no good options for me to make a reasonable on-time module purchase to at least get something resembling what I need.